# How to click 2 buttons on the same page using Scrapy + Splash?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

There is a page where after clicking the link popup notification appears.
So, to follow the link lua script should click on button 1, then click on button 2 (Accept on popup notification) and then proceed to the next page.
My script does not click on button 2. 
Where am I wrong?

```
class PalmBeachSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name ='splash'
    custom_settings = {
        'SPLASH_URL' : 'http://localhost:8050',
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES' : {
                                    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
                                    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
                                    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
                                },
        'SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES' : {
                                'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
                                             }
    }






    script = '''
                function main(splash, args)
                assert(splash:go(args.url))
                assert(splash:wait(0.5))
                assert(splash:runjs('document.querySelector("#bodySection > div > div > div:nth-child(7) > div > div:nth-child(2) > a").click()'))
                assert(splash:wait(3.5))
                assert(splash:runjs('document.querySelector("a#idAcceptYes").click()'))
                return {
                html = splash:html(),


                  }
                end'''
    def start_requests(self):
        url  = 'https://apps.stjohnsclerk.com/Landmark'
        yield SplashRequest(url = url, callback = self.parse, endpoint = 'execute', args={'wait': 0.5, 'lua_source' : self.script})

    def parse(self, response):
        inspect_response(response, self)
        response = HtmlResponse(url=response.url, body=response.data['html'], encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add another 'assert(splash:wait(...))' after the last splash:runjs.